# Modelling probability in tabletop games

Tags: probability, statistics

I was wondering, how can I model probabilities in tabletop games which use D6 dice?

For example, if we would like to shoot on some target, we have to

1. Hit the target
2. Inflict wound on target
3. Target has to take a save, to stay alive

Now, I have a question, how can I model this mathematically?
Say, to hit we have to throw values 3+, to inflict wound 4+ and if target wants to stay alive it has to throw 3+ on its save throw. Will the probability of target dying be just
$$\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{6}\text{?}$$
And what if we will have multiple shots using this scheme?

Comment: As long as the conditions are independent, your approach works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply multiply the probabilities as long as they are independent from each other (which they are in case of throwing a dice).

Shooting twice would just add to the chain:

$$\frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \approx 0.0493$$

This is the probability of survival after two shots.